# How to solve the differential equation $x \dfrac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac {y^{2}}{1 - y\log x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve the differential equation $x \dfrac {dy}{dx} = \dfrac {y^{2}}{1 - y\log x}$ ?

Does not seem like an easy one or reducible to LDE.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the base of log?

Comment: @Battani 'e' the number

Comment: Substitute $\ln{x}=t$. Then, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{y^2}{1-ty}$.

Answer (score 2):

After substitution $\ln{x}=t$, we have $\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{y^2}{1-ty}$. Then, after subtituting $u=y t$ we have $(1-u)\frac{t du-u dt}{t^2}=\frac{u^2}{t^2}dt$, from where we get $\frac{1-u}{u}du=\frac{dt}{t}$ and $\ln{u}-u=\ln{t}+C$. Finally, we have $\frac{u}{e^u}=C_1 t$ and we get implicitly defined solution y:$$\frac{y\ln{x}}{e^{y\ln{x}}}=C_1\ln{x}$$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{y\ln x}{e^{y\ln x}}=C_1\ln x$ simplifies to $yx^{-y}=C_1$

Answer (score 1):

Just to finish alans's answer and taking into account Will Fisher's comment, the solution of $$y\,x^{-y}=c$$ is given explicitely using [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$y=-\frac{W(-c \log (x))}{\log (x)}$$